# Align 2 spans below an image in a div with CSS

Tags: css, html

I have 3 elements in a div: 2 spans and an image. I need to align both spans below the image, one span on the left and one on the right. The div's width is 180px (if that matters). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <img src="" width="" height="" alt="" />
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

CSS styles

```
div { overflow: hidden; width: 180px; }
span { display: block; }
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }
```

That should work, if the image doesn't fill the div element, add "*clear: both*" to *.left*

Comment: You made it looks so easy! Thanks.